# Como colocar a cor de fundo nas células da primeira linha utilizando o NPOI?

Tags: c#, npoi

Estou utilizando a biblioteca NPOI para poder gerar um arquivo Excel.

É a primeira vez que estou tendo contato com essa biblioteca e gostaria de ajuda para colocar cor de fundo nas células da primeira linha.

O meu código atual é esse:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.HSSF.Util;

namespace Excel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var wb = new HSSFWorkbook();

            var sheet = wb.CreateSheet("Model");

            var header = sheet.CreateRow(0);

            header.CreateCell(0).SetCellValue("Title");

            header.CreateCell(1).SetCellValue("Text");

            string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".xls");

            using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                wb.Write(stream);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Crie um novo *style*, defina as propriedades **`FillPattern`** como `FillPatternType.SOLID_FOREGROUND` e **`FillForegroundColor`** com a cor que deseja.

Depois defina este *style* como `CellStyle` das células do *header*.

Veja um exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using NPOI.HSSF.UserModel;
using NPOI.HSSF.Util;


namespace Excel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {    
            var wb = new HSSFWorkbook();    
            var sheet = wb.CreateSheet("Model");    
            var header = sheet.CreateRow(0);

            ICellStyle hStyle = wb.CreateCellStyle();
            hStyle.FillForegroundColor = NPOI.HSSF.Util.HSSFColor.Grey25Precent.index;
            hStyle.FillPattern = FillPatternType.SolidForeground;


            var cell0 = header.CreateCell(0);    
            cell0.SetCellValue("Title");
            cell0.CellStyle = hStyle;

            var cell1 = header.CreateCell(1)
            cell1.SetCellValue("Text");
            cell1.CellStyle = hStyle;

            string filename = Path.Combine(Path.GetTempPath(), Path.GetRandomFileName() + ".xls");

            using (var stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create))
            {
                wb.Write(stream);
            }
        }

    }
}
```